# PowerPoint "new" tab different interface for templates

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, templates

I am doing some tests with personal templates in PowerPoint and I have a problem.
The interface between 2 computers is not the same and I don't know why. In the first computer when I click "new" I have a personal tab with my custom template directly there but in a second computer there is a "custom" tab with 2 folders: "PowerPoint" and "Document Themes":

[image: First PC]

[image: Second PC]

I would like to have the personal tab everywhere. The computers have  the same windows 10 and PowerPoint versions.